# MYSQL - join 2 tables - sort in time

Tags: mysql, join

In my database I have 2 Tables. The first Table (t1) contain general information (id, address etc.). The second Table (t2) contains measurements (id, timestamp, measurement value).

I am trying to query the database in order to get the lastest measurements for each Id.

To illustrate I created t1 and t2 and run the following:

```
SELECT          t2.val, t2.id, t2.ts, t1.address 
FROM            t2 
INNER JOIN      t1  
   ON           t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY        t2.id
ORDER BY        t2.ts desc;
```

Here the result is that I do NOT get the latest records listed. E.g. I get the following (not the latest).

[image: Result from the above query]

The latest records stored in the database are one month later. How to get per Id the latest record while using JOIN to get the Address from t1?

Thanks

Comment: MySQL 5.x or 8.x? It should be easy in 8.x

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: You don't use any aggregate functions, so you're just getting some random rows. Do yourself a favor and activate the sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, so you learn how to use group by correctly.

Comment: Why did you use `group by` but you don't use any aggregate functions

Comment: innodb_version 5.7.24
protocol_version 10

Comment: You are right - the `group by` is not useful here

Answer (score 2):

try to find a bigger time, if you can't you have the latest time

```
SELECT          t2.val, t2.id, t2.ts, t1.address 
FROM            t2 
INNER JOIN      t1  
   ON           t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN       t2 as times
   ON           t2.ts < times.ts
  AND           t2.id = times.id
WHERE times.ts is NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Juan. I tried and it gives me the latest of the entire Table and not the latest for each Id.

Comment: check again. I add the `t2.id  = times.id` condition

Comment: Thanks this is working like a charm. I am going to play with it and learn.
Really appreciate your support.

Comment: Hi Juan, it works in Tables with small number of records. Now I tried in a Table with more records (approx. 300.000) and there the query does not finish (after 30 seconds the connection to the MySQL server is dropped).

Comment: You need create index on t1(id) and t2(id, ts)